# in Azure DevOps, where are the stages of a pipeline actually run?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-deployment

I'm coming to Azure DevOps from my experience with Jenkins, where it was clear that the code in the pipelines being run is actually run on the Jenkins server (whatever machine is hosting that).  So I assumed that Azure DevOps pipelines were running somehow somewhere on https://dev.azure.com/.  Maybe this is true, maybe it isn't.  Maybe it depends on how the "environment" is set up and what resources are in that environment.  My multi-stage pipeline looks like this:

```html
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'



stages: 
- stage: build
  displayName: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build


    steps:

    - checkout: self


    #without this first one, bad things happen!!
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
        
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'


- stage: Release
  displayName: Release
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:

  - deployment:
    displayName: Release
    environment: 
        name: QA
        resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            inputs:  
              SourceFolder: '$(Agent.WorkFolder)\1\drop'
              Contents: '**\*.zip'
              OverWrite: true
              TargetFolder: 'C:\QA\XXX\YYY'
```

I know that 'C:\QA\XXX\YYY' is on the server I am deploying to (a resource in the QA Azure DevOps environment).  But where are these locations?

$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

$(Agent.WorkFolder)

Some of these have "D:" in their path, and yet there is no D: on the server I am deploying to.  Microsoft's documentation never really seems to address this issue, and yet understanding it would seem to be essential to anyone trying to get up to speed with Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline runs on the [agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops), which can be located in one of two places:

[Microsoft-Hosted Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops) each run on a single-purpose VM which is freshly created by Microsoft, and destroyed after a single pipeline job is finished.

[Self-Hosted Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) are run by you, on your infrastructure (either locally or in the cloud). It's normal for them to persist, and run multiple jobs. You can run them:

- on a local physical server
- on an Azure VM
- on an Azure VMSS

Whatever kind of agent you use, those pre-defined variables (*$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)* and *$(Agent.WorkFolder)*) correspond to local file locations on the server where the agent is running.

Your choice of the "windows-latest" pool means that your pipeline runs on a Microsoft-hosted agent, on a Windows VM.

Comment: i wish microsoft itself would give this information somewhere.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
pool:
   vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

That's the pool you're specifying where your jobs should run.

Your deployment job is using the `runOnce` strategy, which is telling it to run that deployment job a single time on the `windows-latest` agent pool. If you want to run a job across machines within an environment, you need to use an appropriate [deployment strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment-strategy?view=azure-pipelines), such as `rolling` or `canary`.

Comment: just to be clear, where, PHYSICALLY is the agent pool?  is it somehow on the resource I am targeting, or is it a virtual server provided by Microsoft for Azure DevOps?  Can I Remote Desktop into it?  Can I browse its directories?  What (if anything) does it provide me beyond the running of tasks in my pipeline?

Comment: and could the reason I am suddenly getting errors such as "The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found." -- does this mean Microsoft updated windows-latest to remove that framework?

Comment: If you're using a Microsoft-hosted agent pool, the answer to all of that is "no". Think of it as a temporary, throw-away work area for your pipelines that Microsoft controls. You can set up your own self-hosted agents and add them to a separate agent pool if you'd like, as well.

Comment: Interestingly, I found that when I changed by vmImage from 'windows-latest' to 'windows-2019' the "The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found." error went away, confirming that the build environment is on that vmImage and that on or around Feb 8th, 2022, Microsoft must've either changed windows-latest to windows-2022 (it had been windows-2019) or removed .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 from windows-latest.  Thanks for your help guiding me to the answer, Daniel!

Comment: @DanielMann your answer doesn't really answer the OP's question. Your *comment*, however, very much does.

Comment: you can see on GitHub what software is included on the MSFT-hosted build agents. See here for windows-latest and .NET Framework verison: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#net-framework

Comment: oh wow, the cause of my lack of that .NET Framework was indeed Microsoft changing windows-latest from Windows 2019 to Windows 2022.  see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-198-update